Solving for a set of of variables when it appears in both numerator and denominator of exp function
I have an expression of form:
\begin{equation}
q_i = \frac{e^{s_i}}{e^{s_1}+...+e^{s_n}}  \;\; i = 1...n
\end{equation}
All the $q_i$'s are known, and I would like to solve for $s_1...s_n$. This seems like a grade school problem, but I can't seem to wrap my head around it. It's a system of equations with $n$ equations and $n$ unknowns. Clearly it can be solved.

First step is to write $t_i$ for $e^{s_i}$ and solve for $t_i$'s.

what's $t_i$ ? I can rearrange and log both sides to get $s_i = ln(p_i) + ln(e^{s_1}+...+e^{s_n})$, but that doesn't get my anywhere.

Note the sum of the $q_i$ must be $1$.

First thing to notice is that your solution will be defined up to an additive constant. Indeed, if $(s_1, \dots, s_n)$ is a solution, then for all $s\in \mathbb{R}$, $(s_1+s, \dots, s_n+s)$ is also a solution.
Because of this, let us fix the solution such that $e^{s_1}+\dots+e^{s_n} = 1$. This yields $$s_i = \ln(q_i)$$ and the general solution is
$$(\ln(q_1), \dots, \ln(q_n)) + s*(1, \dots, 1).$$
The reason why you don't have a unique solution is because you only have $n-1$ independent equations.
